# repin function of a python script won't work

Tags: python, pinterest

I am a newbie regarding python, and still learning,  I am trying to make a script that is on Github works as stated to do some task on Pinterest, I am only interested in Repin other people's pin to my board, I have been trying it for over a week on without any result, Perhaps some people are willing to help me out on this.
I am really grateful.
[Here is the source file link on Github](https://github.com/bstoilov/py3-pinterest)

this is part of the code for repinning:

```
 def repin(pin_id='', board_id='', section_id=None): return pinterest.repin(board_id=board_id,
  pin_id=pin_id, section_id=section_id)
```

I have made a file and have these on it:

```
    import json
    import time
    import os
    from py3pin.Pinterest import Pinterest
    pinterest = Pinterest(email='my acc email',
    password='my acc pass',
    username='my acc username',
    cred_root='cred_root')
    def repin(pin_id='I put other's people pin no Here', board_id='I put one of my board id number 
    Here', section_id=None):
    return pinterest.repin(board_id=board_id, pin_id=pin_id, section_id=section_id)
```

I don't get any results and don't get any error either.
I appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json
import time
import os
from py3pin.Pinterest import Pinterest
pinterest = Pinterest(email='my acc email',
password='my acc pass',
username='my acc username',
cred_root='cred_root')
pinterest.login()
def repin(pin_id="403212972893719260",board_id="403213041577459796"):
  pinterest.repin(board_id=board_id,pin_id=pin_id)

repin()
```

The only error I got was a login error because the credentials are invalid.

Side Note: The ids are placeholders, random.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried it and it worked. Thank you agin

Comment: Alright, would you mind to accept my answer? @Dave99